# Dnschef: Fail to open log file?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, dns

I'm usin `dnschef` in my Linux machine, but it gave me this error.

How to fix this issue?

[image: screenshot]

Plus, I can use `dnschef` (which will use localhost network card lo by default) and it doesn't have such issue.

Comment: you haven’t provided the —logfile parameter, but it appears there are [several issues](https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef/issues/7) with the software’s error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://thesprawl.org/projects/dnschef/). It shows you the various ways you can use `dnschef`.

> DNSChef is capable of storing activity log in an external file using the `--logfile log1.txt` command line parameter. Below is a snippet of a sample DNSChef session:

So something like this:

```
$ dnschef -i wlan0 --logfile /tmp/dnschef.log
```

#### The full usage

```
root@kali:~# dnschef -h
Usage: dnschef.py [options]:
          _                _          __
         | | version 0.1  | |        / _|
       __| |_ __  ___  ___| |__   ___| |_
      / _` | '_ \/ __|/ __| '_ \ / _ \  _|
     | (_| | | | \__ \ (__| | | |  __/ |
      \__,_|_| |_|___/\___|_| |_|\___|_|
                   iphelix@thesprawl.org


DNSChef is a highly configurable DNS Proxy for Penetration Testers and Malware
Analysts. It is capable of fine configuration of which DNS replies to modify
or to simply proxy with real responses. In order to take advantage of the tool
you must either manually configure or poison DNS server entry to point to
DNSChef. The tool requires root privileges to run.

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --fakeip=192.168.1.100
                        IP address to use for matching DNS queries. If you use
                        this parameter without specifying domain names, then
                        all queries will be spoofed. Consider using --file
                        argument if you need to define more than one IP
                        address.
  --fakedomains=thesprawl.org,google.com
                        A comma separated list of domain names which will be
                        resolved to a FAKE value specified in the --ip
                        parameter. All other domain names will be resolved to
                        their true values.
  --truedomains=thesprawl.org,google.com
                        A comma separated list of domain names which will be
                        resolved to their TRUE values. All other domain names
                        will be resolved to a fake value specified in the --ip
                        parameter.
  --nameservers=4.2.2.1,4.2.2.2
                        A comma separated list of alternative DNS servers to
                        use with proxied requests. A randomly selected server
                        from the list will be used for proxy requests. By
                        default, the tool uses Google's public DNS server
                        8.8.8.8.
  --file=FILE           Specify a file containing a list of DOMAIN=IP pairs
                        (one pair per line) used for DNS responses. For
                        example: google.com=1.1.1.1 will force all queries to
                        'google.com' to be resolved to '1.1.1.1'. You can be
                        even more specific by combining --file with other
                        arguments. However, data obtained from the file will
                        take precedence over others.
  --interface=0.0.0.0   Define an interface to use for the DNS listener. For
                        example, use 127.0.0.1 to listen for only requests
                        coming from a loopback device.
  --tcp                 Use TCP DNS proxy instead of the default UDP.
  -q, --quiet           Don't show headers.
```

#### Issue #10 - cannot open logfile

Your issue looks like it's actually a false positive though. The real error is this:

> IOError code 13 (permission denied) is thrown on an attempt to bind to the default port 53 which requires the root permissions

I found that here in the upstream repo for `dnschef` - https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef/issues/10.

In the comments people are stating that this issue is still not resolved, and even when running `dnschef` as root, it's still reporting the error.

#### Bottom line

Sounds like a bug in `dnschef`.

#### References

- https://tools.kali.org/sniffingspoofing/dnschef
- https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef